# R ggplot2: Including Multiple Trendlines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot three time-series line plots and include a linear trendline for each of them. I'm using ggplot2. Here's what I have:

```
p<- ggplot(bds, aes(year2)) + 
geom_line(aes(y = estabs_entry_rate, colour = "Entry Rate")) + 
geom_smooth(method="lm") + 
geom_line(aes(y = estabs_exit_rate, colour = "Exit Rate")) +
geom_smooth(method="lm") +
geom_line(aes(y=job_creation_rate-job_destruction_rate+5, colour="Net Jobs")) +
geom_smooth(method="lm")
p
```

I tried to include `geom_smooth(method="lm")` after each `geom_line()` call. However I'm getting the following error message:

Error: stat_smooth requires the following missing aesthetics: y

What I'd like is a plot of `estabs_entry_rate`, `estabs_exit_rate` and `job_creation_rate-job_destruction_rate` vs time, all on one plot, with a linear trendline for each.

How can I do this in ggplot2?

Thanks very much in advance.

EDIT: Here is an example of the `bds` data:

```
year2   estabs_entry_rate   estabs_exit_rate   job_creat_rate   job_destr_rate
1982    15.4                11.5                18.3            17.0
1983    12.6                11.4                18.2            18.6
1984    14.3                10.9                16.5            13.6
1985    14.0                10.5                19.8            15.6
```

Comment: What is `bds`? Could you share a reproducible example of `bds` so we can study it?

Comment: reshape the data from long to wide, then plot with adding a group variable e.g. color, fill, or shape.

Comment: You need to define a `y` variable for each `geom_smooth` call like you did with `geom_line`.

Comment: Reshape your data from wide to long (I'm guessing that's what @Jimbou actually meant). If you provide a data sample, we can provide code specific to your problem. For now, here's an example with the built-in `iris` data frame: `library(tidyverse); ggplot(gather(iris, key, value, -Species, -Petal.Width), aes(Petal.Width, value, colour=key, fill=key)) + geom_smooth(method="lm")`

Comment: Yes sorry, `bds` has `year` `estabs_entry_rate`, `estabs_exit_rate`, `job_creation_rate` and `job_destruction_rate` as columns.

Comment: `library(tidyverse); ggplot(gather(bds, key, value, -year), aes(year, value, colour=key, fill=key)) + geom_smooth(method="lm")`

Comment: Thank you - when I do that though, I get the following error: 

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (950): x, y, colour, fill

Comment: aosmith, could you please explain how to define a `y` for each `geom_smooth` call?